# Post Processing without using FBOs?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, post-processing, vertex-shader

Recently, I've been making a 3D game (hint my questions), and I recently have modified a pixelization shader from a unity shader graph tutorial. The thing is, I want to render the shader on the WHOLE screen, not just a single object, but while researching, I've come across something called *[Framebuffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)* (FBOs), which make it pretty much easier (basically just grabs the frame and turns it into an image for you to "process" it before it gets rendered on the screen), but I don't really want to use FBOs. How would I come across doing this? I've researched a little and came across using a quad, but since my game is 3D, not 2D, I have a perspective camera, so I don't know how that would turn out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a game engine? If yes, your game engine likely comes in with a built in post-processing system/pipeline, in which case you shouldn't have to worry about frame buffers for simple post-processing.

If your engine doesn't have a post-fx system, or you're making an engine from scratch: yes you would use a quad. The key, is that instead of rendering/transforming the quad in *world-space* you would render and position it in *view-space* so it will be fixed in the screen instead of in the world. You'll do this changing whatever transformation matrix is being used to displace the quads vertices to a view-space-matrix.

You might want to familiarize yourself with the purpose of matrices (which effectively act as stores for transformations in 3D games) and the basic graphics / shader pipeline.

Here's a [link](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) which offers an overview of the role of *matrices* and *spaces* in realtime 3D rendering.

Comment: no, im using LWJGL

Comment: and I am using depreciated methods, so no binding vaos and vbos

Comment: hmm im not familiar with non-modern open GL or LWJGL: but the key is change the transformation matrix for the quad from world-space to view space. Then you can set the quads vertices effectively in 2D space.

Comment: So like, use a different fragment and vertex shader file to convert the matrices into a view matrix, rendering the quad flat on the screen.

Comment: if so, then how does the shading exactly work? like how do I post process a quad to make it for all objects on the screen

Comment: the logic is melting my brain

Comment: Yeah, typically you could just feed a different transformation matrix to your vertex/fragment shaders on the java side of things. But if that's not possible in LWJGL then you can just make separate shaders. You'll set the quad vertices between -1 to 1. The quad will then cover the entire screen. You can then make your quad semi-transparent, and perhaps tint the screen. Certain versions of OpenGL even let you read from the current textures pixel in the frag shader so you can have some slightly more dynamic post-fx then simple tints. There will be some limitations doing things with FBOs though.

Comment: I’m not talking about simple tints, I’m talking about literally changing how the render is viewed. Like pixelization or even bloom (maybe?)

Comment: For more complex post-fx, you'll have to use FBOs. With the above method described, you're limited in what you can actually read from. You don't have full access to read from the texture that you're currently writing to. Good luck!

Comment: so I can do simple effects that will overlay on the screen without using FBOs, but I have to use FBOs to make complex effects like bloom or things that modify the render alltogether

Comment: how would I make an fbo using the old methods? like I dont use vaos, vbos, or rbos at all

Comment: Yes, you need FBOs for more complex effects where you need to sample the screen as a texture. Sorry I'm not familiar with those old openGL stuff.

Comment: I'm trying to use [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/), but either the quad renders black or the quad doesn't modify anything

Comment: its now sortof working? its pure black but when I start theres a TINY amount of flicker at the start that shows the cube but then it goes black again